# Annotation difference between justRMA and read.affybatch

Tags: bioconductor

I am trying to get the raw expression data from a CEL file with probe names. However I could not get the probe names.

I tried using `read.affybatch` as the following:

```
library(affy)
smallest_file <- "GSM766572.CEL.gz"    
setwd("/data0/RtmpGPL/raw")
a <- read.affybatch(smallest_file)
c <- justRMA(filenames = c(smallest_file), normalize=FALSE)
```

however when I inspect the content with

```
head(exprs(a))
```

the content was

```
  GSM766572.CEL.gz
1              157
2            15900
3              171
4            15673
5               56
6              115
```

what I want is something like the below (which was produced with `head(exprs(c))` )

```
          GSM766572.CEL.gz
1007_s_at         9.636495
1053_at           6.574971
117_at            5.966103
121_at            8.559288
1255_g_at         4.508790
1294_at           8.320684
```

But with the raw expression levels.

I do not understand why I can not get the probe names with the raw expression levels. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [justrma code](https://github.com/Bioconductor-mirror/affy/blob/5c27fb26ca720efc4a7af1361ee40f7feccbca19/R/justrma.R) and [a solution](http://grokbase.com/p/r/bioconductor/115j91dqgz/bioc-extract-intensity-values-from-affybatch) I guess that what I wanted can be achieved by the following way:

```
tmp <- ReadAffy(filenames=c("GSM766572.CEL.gz"),celfile.path = "/data0/RtmpGPL/raw")
pmIndex <- pmindex(tmp)
probeintensities <- pm(tmp)
probenames <- rep(names(pmIndex), unlist(lapply(pmIndex,length)))
rownames(probeintensities) <- probenames
```

this produces something like the below:

```
          GSM766572.CEL.gz
1007_s_at            352.0
1007_s_at            790.0
1007_s_at            853.0
1007_s_at           4383.5
1007_s_at           3090.0
1007_s_at           2239.0
```